# Attached sqlite databases and multithreading issues in Android

Tags: android, multithreading, android-sqlite

I would like to understand the issues involved in multithreaded access to ATTACHED sqlite databases. What is clear is that one `SQLiteOpenHelper` ensures one database connection and thus one serialized access to a database. What happens when one 'child' database is attached twice, under two different 'parent' `SQLiteOpenHelper`s / two different parent database connections?

Q1: How is access to the attached child database serialized?

Q2: How is write ahead logging implemented in this scenario?

To be clear, this is the scenario I am describing:

```
ASQLiteOpenHelper instanceA = new ASQLiteOpenHelper( context, dbnameA, null, version);
BSQLiteOpenHelper instanceB = new BSQLiteOpenHelper( context, dbnameB, null, version);

instanceA.getWritableDatabase().execSQL( "ATTACH '" + dbnameChild + "' AS child" );
instanceB.getWritableDatabase().execSQL( "ATTACH '" + dbnameChild + "' AS child" );
```

Is writing to 'child' via `instanceA` and `instanceB` concurrently safe? What about reading? If enabling writeahead logging for the parent, is it also enabled for the child? If yes, are two separate write ahead logging journals created for the `child`?

Comment: It looks that `DB` is a shared resource and multiple instances of `SQLiteOpenHelpers` are accessing `DB`. Please correct me if i mis-interpretted your scenario.

Comment: I think you are mis-interpreting my scenario. There are three separate databases: dbnameA, dbnameB, and dbnameChild. The two helpers each open a different database. However, the third database, dbnameChild, is attached under both helpers.

Comment: So , dbnameChild is a shared resource for both helpers. Isn't it

Comment: Indirectly, yes, as a result of being attached from both helpers.

Comment: So you need to `synchronize` the access to the DB now. put, the code in synchronize block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some testing I found out that the `ATTACH`ed database will be locked on the first `ATTACH` attempt. Further `ATTACH` attempts will fail.

Answer (score 0):

From [here](https://sqlite.org/faq.html):

> We are aware of no other embedded SQL database engine that supports as
>   much concurrency as SQLite. SQLite allows multiple processes to have
>   the database file open at once, and for multiple processes to read the
>   database at once. When any process wants to write, it must lock the
>   entire database file for the duration of its update. But that normally
>   only takes a few milliseconds. Other processes just wait on the writer
>   to finish then continue about their business. Other embedded SQL
>   database engines typically only allow a single process to connect to
>   the database at once.

And [here](http://sqlite.org/lockingv3.html) is a huge amount of information on concurrency.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't address my concern, because a locked database in Android will result in a runtime exception. This is why SQLiteOpenHelper is used as a singleton - to ensure only one database connection is used for reading/writing. My question was about the consequencies of attaching databases in a multithreading scenario.

Comment: @zyamys I should have read better.. it's late at night here! :(